# Python: Programmatically compiling a Python package into pyc or pyo files

Tags: python, compilation, pyc

This is for my test suite.

I have an automatically-generated Python package in a temporary folder. It's all `.py` files. I want to programmatically compile these into (a) `.pyc` and (b) `.pyo` files. (One test will do `.pyc`, another will do `.pyo`.) This should be done with the active interpreter, of course. I do not want to import the modules, just compile.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your Python lib directory, there will be a script called `compileall.py` (e.g., `/usr/lib/python2.6/compileall.py`).

In your code, spawn (e.g., by using `os.spawnl`) an invocation of `compileall.py` pointed at the directory containing your generated code.  If you invoke it using `python -O` it will generate `.pyo` files; if you invoke it using `python` it will generate `.pyc` file.

The trick, I suppose, would be to call with the right version of the Python interpreter.

`compileall.py` uses `py_compile` under the hood.

Comment: Note that the correct way to invoke the `compileall` module is using `python -m compileall`, NOT `python /path/to/compileall.py`. And figure out the location of the Python interpreter via `sys.executable`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the [`py_compile`](http://docs.python.org/library/py_compile.html) module. Sadly it won't let you choose between `pyo` and `pyc`.

Comment: The `-O` argument to `python` will though.

Comment: Yes, if it's fine to launch a separately parametrized python interpreter for each of the test configurations, this wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that as long as there is a write permission in a directory from which a python module (*.py) is imported, the *.pyc file with the same name will be crated. 
Moreover, *.pyc and *.pyo **do not** add any performance to the program, except decreaed modules loading time.

Answer (score 0):

chosing between .pyo and pyc is possible with py_compile

> import py_compile
>
> #### compile as simple bytecode:
>
> py_compile.compile('sourcefilename.py', 'destinationfilename.pyc',
>   doraise=True )
>
> #### compile as optimised bytecode: both '-o'  and  '-oo' can be passed as parameters
>
> py_compile.compile('sourcefilename.py', 'destinationfilename.pyo','-oo',  doraise=True )

I have tried with python 2.7 and it  only seems to work when you pass on all the parameters.